# MongooseError: Operation `therapists.find()` buffering timed out after 10000ms

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, timeout, unhandled-promise-rejection

I have seen this issue published in a few places however I still don't have a solution.

I am using a node server and can connect to my database correctly with a status of 1 for connected.

However when I send requests to the mongodb database, the request pends and times out.

I have tried adding my IP to mongodb, putting my connection in an async function. and also removing mongoose and re installing it.

My structure is like this
app
client
node_modules > mongoose 5.13.14
server
node_modules > mongoose 5.13.14

My connection to mongodb is like this.

```
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGOOSE_CONNECTION,  { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true,  useCreateIndex: true })
.then(res =>{
  console.log("Connected to Database")
}).catch(function (reason) {
  console.log('Unable to connect to the mongodb instance. Error: ', reason);
});
```

An example of an endpoint that fails is here.

```
router.get('/therapists', (req, res) => {
    signUpTemplate.find({}, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            res.status(200).send({
                results: result
            })
        }
    })
})
```

which results in error
`MongooseError: Operation` therapists.find() `buffering timed out after 10000ms`

Can someone help me please as I am really not sure what the solution is.
Thank you!

Comment: Can you post the code where you call the DB connection function and the controller calling the `findOne`?

Comment: yh sure, I just updated my question to show this call @LucaPizzini

Comment: Where are you calling the `mongoose.connect`? In the `index.js` file?

Comment: in server.js which is in the server directory @LucaPizzini